# dacpac file Publish error to LocalDB: "The element cannot be deployed. This element contains state that cannot be recreated in the target database."

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, ssms, database-backups

Pretty simple you would think, but as I cannot edit the schema in this database I have no idea how to get past this error when I am publishing my dacpac file to my local database. I am trying to take a copy of a database that is hosted in Azure and have it locally for my own development purposes. I am not a sysadmin of the database, but I have complete access to it other than that. It is a production database so I can't mess anything up for obvious reasons.

I had a hell of a time even getting this dacpac file created in the first place. I was getting far more errors/warnings when trying to export as a bacpac file with data (which is what I really want to do, but I can worry about that later).

Here is the command I am trying:

```
SqlPackage.exe /Action:Publish /SourceFile:" C:\Data\opkCore.dacpac" /TargetConnectionString:"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=opkCore; Integrated Security=true;"
```

This is what I used to create the dacpac file:

```
sqlpackage.exe /Action:Export /ssn:tcp:<MyDatabase>.database.windows.net,1433 /sdn:opkCore /su:<MyUserName> /sp:<MyPassword> /tf:C:\Data\opkCore.bacpac
```

I have tried other solutions such as:

1. Export Data-tier Application, but I am limited to only doing it in an Azure container and I am not in control of that. It is a Pay-As-You-Go model which does not support blob storage apparently
2. Copy Database only works for  2005 and earlier and this is SQL 2019
3. Deploy Database to Microsoft SQL Server Azure SQL Database
4. Import Data-tier Application, same problem as #1
5. Exporting bacpac file using SqlPackage.exe - Errors all over the place that I cannot fix. The database is not mine to mess up

I CAN export tables one at a time, but then I am missing certain bits of schema that work together, so I get errors there also.

I really should be able to just get a local copy of the database in the EXACT same state that it currently is on our production server. Any other ideas for me on how I can do this that will ignore problems with the database and just get me a local copy the EXACT way the database is in production? 3rd party tools that do this or anything?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to just script all the tables and run the script on my new DB. There were a lot of errors, but it did what it could which was 99.99% of the database schema and that is good enough for my purpose. Maybe I will try to get the data exported and imported as well.

EDIT: To export the data I just used SSMS Export data and the destination used was the new LocalDB database I just created from the scripts.